# IP address already in use Barracuda archiver 350

Tags: passwords, archiving

I am trying to log in to a `barracuda acrhiver 350` but every time I tried to change the IP address of the appliance from the CL , i got the error

> IP Address already in use

No matter what ip address i put.

How to fix that?

Comment: You did verify that the address isn’t in use, right?

Comment: Yes, I also disconnected the appliance from the network and tried different IP addresses , but got the exact same problem